# My list is taking repeat elements and I don't know why

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of strings in a list called "texts". I am trying to scan each string for each of the words in a list called "key_words". If any of the key words is in the string, it goes into "list1". If none of the key words is in the string, it goes into "list2". My goal is for each string to be in its appropriate list once. The problem is that because I have three words in "key_words", a string with any of the words will go into list1 three times. I don't know why this is happening and I've been stuck working on this for an hour even though this seems pretty simple. Any help greatly appreciated.

I have a list of strings in a list called "texts".

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
key_words = ['must', 'should', 'wish']

for text in texts:

    for word in key_words:

        if text not in list1 and text not in list2:

            if word in text:
                 list1.append(text)

            else:
                list2.append(text)
```

Comment: Working on answer. Your code is making unnecessary comparisons and can be done in a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code has a bug:

> If *any* of the keywords are in `text`, it should go to `list1`

However in your code, you immediately copy the text to `list2`, even if the first keyword is not present. The trick to solve this simply is in the quote above. Here is a simple and efficient solution:

```
import re

keyword_regex = '|'.join(key_words)  # Compile the regex if you have to use many times

for text in texts:
    if re.search(keyword_regex, text):  # Success if any keyword is in text
        list1.append(text)
    else:
        list2.append(text)
```

Comment: That makes complete sense. It's difficult for me to visualize what my code is doing sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Would appreciate if you could choose an accepted answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looping over the keywords you are adding the text to lists multiple times.

```py
list1 = []
list2 = []
key_words = ['must', 'should', 'wish']
texts = ["must the a hooray", "hooray should the a", "a the an"]

for text in texts:

    found = False
    if text not in list1 and text not in list2:
        for word in key_words:

                if word in text:
                     found = True
                     break
        if found:
            list1.append(text)
        else:
            list2.append(text)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Generates:

> ['must the a hooray', 'hooray should the a']
>
> ['a the an']

Answer (score 0):

It will scan through the entire text document and add the "text" word to a respective list if the "text" word has not been previously inserted.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
key_words = ['must', 'should', 'wish']

for text in texts:
    for word in key_words:
       if (word in text and not in list1):
          list1.append(text)
       elif (word not in list2):
          list2.append(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan the words in the `text`, not in the `key_words` list. The latter is just used to check the condition and decide for `list1` or `list2`.

This is an option using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall) library for **splitting** the text in words, **without punctuation**. Once you have the list of words, you can iterate over it and check if each word in in `key_words`.

In the following example I'm using just one text string, you can extend the code for a list of texts.

This is what happen to `text` when applying the `re.findal`l method:

```
text = 'Must the show go on? I wish, it should! It must.'
print(re.findall(r'\w+',text))
#=> ['Must', 'the', 'show', 'go', 'on', 'I', 'wish', 'it', 'should', 'It', 'must']
```

The lookup on the text is performed once as the loop starts, here the complete code:

```
for txt_word in re.findall(r'\w+',text):
  if txt_word.lower() in key_words: # <- note .lower()
    list1.append(txt_word) # just add if not in list1 if you don't want duplicates
  else:
    list2.append(txt_word)
```

This is the output:

```
print(list1) #=>['Must', 'wish', 'should', 'must']
print(list2) #=> ['the', 'show', 'go', 'on', 'I', 'it', 'It']
```